# How can I get the game to show the word after all guesses have been used up?

Tags: swift, text, label

so I'm new to coding and I've been doing practice games a such to build my skills. I've created this word guessing game and I'm trying to make the game show the word after all guesses have been used up. However, the program doesn't read the code I write to set the label to display the answer. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var listOfWords = ["ladybug", "program", "computer", "language", "glorious", "incandescent"]
    let incorrectMovesAllowed = 7

    var totalWins = 0 {
        didSet {
            newRound()
        }
    }

    var totalLosses = 0 {
        didSet {
            newRound()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var letterButtons: [UIButton]!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
        let letterString = sender.title(for: .normal)!
        let letter = Character(letterString.lowercased())
        currentGame.playerGuessed(letter: letter)
        updateUI()
        updateGameState()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var correctWordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var treeImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newRound()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func enableLetterButtons (_enable: Bool){
        for button in letterButtons {
            button.isEnabled = _enable
        }
    }

    var currentGame : Game!

    func newRound() {
        if !listOfWords.isEmpty{
           let newWord = listOfWords.removeFirst()
            currentGame = Game (word: newWord, incorrectMovesRemaining: incorrectMovesAllowed, guessedLetters: [])
            enableLetterButtons(_enable: true)
            updateUI()
        } else {
            enableLetterButtons (_enable: false)
        }

    }

    func updateUI() {
        var letters = [String] ()
        for letter in currentGame.formattedWord.characters {
            letters.append(String(letter))
        }
        let wordWithSpacing = letters.joined(separator: " ")
        correctWordLabel.text = wordWithSpacing
        scoreLabel.text = "Wins: \(totalWins), Losses:\(totalLosses)"
        treeImageView.image = UIImage (named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)")
    }

    func updateGameState(){
       var letters = [String] ()
        for letter in currentGame.word.characters {
            letters.append(String(letter))
        }
        let theAnswer = letters.joined(separator: " ")
        if currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining == 0 {
            correctWordLabel.text = theAnswer
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
            totalLosses += 1
        } else if currentGame.word == currentGame.formattedWord {
            totalWins += 1
        } else {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, I have a structure that is written like this:

```
import Foundation
struct Game {
    var word : String
    var incorrectMovesRemaining : Int
    var guessedLetters: [Character]
    mutating func playerGuessed (letter: Character){
        guessedLetters.append(letter)
        if !word.characters.contains(letter){
            incorrectMovesRemaining -= 1
        }
    }
    var formattedWord: String {
        var guessedWord = ""
        for letter in word.characters {
            if guessedLetters.contains(letter) {
                guessedWord += "\(letter)"
            } else {
                guessedWord += "_"
            }
        }
        return guessedWord
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the issue that the program isn't changing the `label` to what you want?

Comment: At the end of your `updateUI()` function you should call `self.setNeedsDisplay()` to let the system know that your UI needs to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redraw your UI, this is done with `self.setNeedsDisplay()`. It notifies the system that the view's contents needs to be redrawn. In your `updateUI()` you can add this. 
Regarding setNeedsDisplay you can get more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var listOfWords = ["ladybug", "program", "computer", "language", "glorious", "incandescent"]
    let incorrectMovesAllowed = 7
    var totalWins = 0 {
        didSet {
            newRound()
        }
    }

    var totalLosses = 0 {
        didSet {
            newRound()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var letterButtons: [UIButton]!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
        let letterString = sender.title(for: .normal)!
        let letter = Character(letterString.lowercased())
        currentGame.playerGuessed(letter: letter)
        updateUI()
        updateGameState()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var correctWordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var treeImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newRound()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func enableLetterButtons (_enable: Bool){
        for button in letterButtons {
            button.isEnabled = _enable
        }
    }

    var currentGame : Game!

    func newRound() {
        if !listOfWords.isEmpty{
           let newWord = listOfWords.removeFirst()
            currentGame = Game (word: newWord, incorrectMovesRemaining: incorrectMovesAllowed, guessedLetters: [])
            enableLetterButtons(_enable: true)
            updateUI()
        } else {
            enableLetterButtons (_enable: false)
        }

    }

    func updateUI() {
        var letters = [String] ()
        for letter in currentGame.formattedWord.characters {
            letters.append(String(letter))
        }
        let wordWithSpacing = letters.joined(separator: " ")
        correctWordLabel.text = wordWithSpacing
        scoreLabel.text = "Wins: \(totalWins), Losses:\(totalLosses)"
        treeImageView.image = UIImage (named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)")
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func updateGameState(){
       var letters = [String] ()
        for letter in currentGame.word.characters {
            letters.append(String(letter))
        }
        let theAnswer = letters.joined(separator: " ")
        if currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining == 0 {
            correctWordLabel.text = theAnswer
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
            totalLosses += 1
        } else if currentGame.word == currentGame.formattedWord {
            totalWins += 1
        } else {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that will keep track of how many times you have guessed wrong. Then you can do this:

Use a while statement:

```
 while numberOfTimesGuessedWrong <= 7{

}
 //when you have guessed incorrectly 7 times, the compiler will move here:
wordLabel.text = "\(correctAnswer)"
```

So when you guess incorrectly 7 times, on the 8th time, it will then show the correct answer.